# Fill PDF Form with dynamic values using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I am stuck here. actually I am trying to fill a PDF form using asp.net. I get some help and write the following code:

```
private void fillForm()
{
    try
    {
        string formFile = Server.MapPath("") + @"\Forms\fw4.pdf";
        string savepath = Server.MapPath("") + @"\Forms\new_fw4.pdf";
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(formFile);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, stream);
            AcroFields formFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in formFields.Fields)
             {
                 formFields.SetField("field name", "field value");
             }            
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

I want the program to show all fields in a List.
I am unable to iterate all available fields using the foreach loop. Its giving me this error:

Cannot convert type `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item>` to `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what about using KeyValuePair<,> instead of DictionaryEntry?

Comment: thnaks for the reply, it works with just var. but now I want to listdown all fields present in the file in an array or some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have updated KeyValuePair try using item.Key & item.Value